# flutter CountryCodePicker i need to remove close icon, from CountryCodePicker dialogBox

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, country-codes

flutter CountryCodePicker i need to remove close icon, need when a user click outside the dialogBox then need to close the Countrycode dialog box.

please check the image,

[image]

```
CountryCodePicker(

              dialogTextStyle:const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
              showOnlyCountryWhenClosed: false,
              dialogSize: Size(
                  ScreenUtil().setWidth(220), ScreenUtil().setHeight(400)),

              onChanged: (code) => {
                print(code),
              },
              boxDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                boxShadow:  [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    offset: Offset(
                      0.5,
                      0.5,
                    ),
                    blurRadius: 50.0.sp,
                    spreadRadius: 17.0.sp,
                  ), //BoxShadow
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                    blurRadius: 0.0,
                    spreadRadius: 0.0,
                  ), //BoxShadow
                ],
                // color:  Color(0xff6200D4).withOpacity(0.90),
              ),
              // Initial selection and favorite can be one of code ('IT') OR dial_code('+39')
              textStyle:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0.sp, color: Colors.black54),
              initialSelection: 'IN',
              favorite: ['+91', 'IN'],
              alignLeft: true,
              onInit: (code) => print(
                  "on init ${code?.name} ${code?.dialCode} ${code?.name}"),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you include sample code that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: sure...please check now..here i need to remove close icon form country code dialog box.and need when a user click outside the dialogBox then need to close the Country code dialog box.

Comment: Are you using any lib for countryCode selection ?

If yes, please try to overwrite that. Else not possible, please create your own.

Comment: close icon is hard-coded on `selection_dialog`

Answer (score 0):

When looking through the packages README I couldn't find any option to hide the Icon. So, you now have the following options:

1. Theming. Set the color of the Icon to transparent, hence the button would not appear visually, but it still would be there.
2. Alter the projects code. You could create a fork of the repository and change the code of the package for your needs.

I would prefer doing the second option. Alternatively, you can directly edit the local clone of the package. However, this is not recommended, because you need to change the same piece of code on every machine or every time you clone the project.